# Select query error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, types, oracle10g

I first created a Type and then created a Table and then inserted 1 row into the table which was successful but when I fire the Select query on Table I get errors:

```
create type My_type as Object
(
fname varchar2(10),
lname varchar2(10)
);
```

Now created the table

```
create table My_table 
(
name My_type,
phone number
);
```

Inserted a row

```
insert into My_table values ( My_type('Abc','Xyz'), 122);
```

Fire the Select query

```
select * from My_table;
```

> Error :   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got OODB.MY_TYPE

```
select name.fname, name.lname, phone from My_table;
```

> Error : ORA-00904: "NAME"."LNAME": invalid identifier

```
select My_type.fname, My_type.lname, phone from My_table;
```

> Error : ORA-00904: "MY_TYPE"."LNAME": invalid identifier

Comment: What client are you using to execute these queries?

Comment: i am using Oracle 10g Express Edition in my Windows XP PC at home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a current version of SQL*Plus, this should work

```
SQL> create type My_type as Object ( fname varchar2(10), lname varchar2(10) );
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table My_table ( name My_type, phone number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into My_table values ( My_type('Abc','Xyz'), 122);

1 row created.

SQL> column name format a30;
SQL> select * from My_table;

NAME(FNAME, LNAME)                  PHONE
------------------------------ ----------
MY_TYPE('Abc', 'Xyz')                 122
```

It is possible that if you're using a really old version of SQL*Plus or if you're using some other client tool that the client tool doesn't know how to handle object types.

Outside of classroom exercises, you don't generally define tables that have object types in the real world.  It's much more common to use object types in PL/SQL code to simplify processing-- dealing with objects that are stored as part of the data model, on the other hand, tends to be problematic.

Comment: what's "column name format a30"; i typed this but it says "Invalid SQL statements"

Comment: @R122 - That's a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement.  It just tells SQL*Plus to display the data in the `NAME` column using 30 characters.  If you omit it, the output in SQL*Plus will potentially wrap to the next line.  But it sounds like you're not using SQL*Plus.

Comment: Superb man! for "column name format a30;" but this time i used sql*plus and the select query was successful but when i try it using Database Home page (i.e. object browser and all ) it gives above error as mentioned in my question.......So why the same query executes in sql*plus and not using the Oracle Database Home page?

Comment: But in "column name format a30" what is "a" ? i tried substituting it with letter "b" and it gives me error?

Comment: @R122 - The `a` in `a30` just indicates that the column should be displayed as a character string (I assume `a` stands for alphabetical).  My guess without doing any testing is that the query tool in the Oracle Database Home page doesn't support displaying user-defined object types (this goes back to the point that object types defined as part of the data model are pretty uncommon outside of homework problems-- lots of tools won't bother to implement support for them).